# Set Focus to Elementor Search Form on Page Load

Tags: focus, elementor

I am trying to set focus to an Elementor Search form.  I have searched everywhere for code to do this but cant not find anything that works with Elementor.  I reached out to Elementor but they say it is not possible.

I can not believe that you have to click twice to get to an input field when it is the only one on a page.

You see the issue on [SilentMedia Website](https://www.silentmedia.co.uk/).  Click the search icon on the left of the page, which calls an Elementor Popup Template, which has just a single Search Element.

If this is not possible with popup I would consider the search icon opening a new page, on which hopefully the search element has focus on page load.

Answer (score 4):

due to Elementor behavior - you can not achieve that using normal way. But you can use this trick. Here are steps for that:

1. check if the search form is exits
2. if exits - Set the pointer to the search form
3. code:

   ```
      setInterval(function(){
      if(jQuery('#autofocus input').length>0){
         jQuery('#autofocus input').focus().val();
         return false;
      }
    }, 500);
   ```
4. In case my answer is not clearly for you, i made a **[short guide video for this](https://youtu.be/-BQgvA-MWks)** here.

Comment: Thanks for this useful code! Is it possible that this code does not work on mobile while it's working on desktop? I tried it on an iPhone 12 Pro with Safari and Chrome and it didn't work. TIA.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks so much for the tutorial!